# Removing trailing whitespace only from some lines

Tags: regex, sed, removing-whitespace

Sometimes I have a patchfile that erroneously adds whitespace to the end of some lines.  Can someone give me a sed script that removes trailing whitespace only on lines that begin with '+'?

Comment: wouldn't it make sense to fix the "patchfile" (whatever that is) to just not do that?

Comment: The tool I use to make the patchfile has a bug that adds the whitespace.  It's much easier for me to clean up the patchfile than it would be to fix the tool.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
sed -E 's/(^\+.*)( $)/\1/'
```

This finds two groups: a line starts with + and then a bunch of characters, followed by a second group that's just a space and the end of the line.  It then just replaces that with the first group alone.

Comment: You could also do `sed '/^+/s/ $//'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`sed -i '/^+/s/[ \t]*$//' file`